# Postgres denormalize tables into json objects for node

Tags: postgresql

Heres my problem. I have the following tables

```
CREATE TABLE inventory(
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    owner text NOT NULL references profile(name)
);

CREATE TABLE inventory_item(
    id uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    description text,
    amount bigint,
    inventory uuid nOT NULL references table(id)
);
```

Now I would like to query for a single inventory

- all items in that inventory
- id and owner of that inventory

So I basically get a result of the following form, to send to the client:

```
{
   "id":"1234123-1234-1234",
   "owner":"tom",
   "items":[
      {
         "id":"2344-123412-34",
         "description":"sword",
         "amount":33
      },
      {
         "id":"6434-123412-34",
         "description":"apple",
         "amount":23
      },
      {
         "id":"45454-1123412-34",
         "description":"bow",
         "amount":32
      },
      {
         "id":"234234-1232412-34",
         "description":"arrow",
         "amount":1
      }
   ]
}
```

I was thinking of querying id and owner directly and then adding the items as a subquery using ARRAY(). Unfortunately, ARRAY() only works with columns of the same type.

So how can I denormalize my table structure into a JSON array for node using a postgres query?

Comment: please add a [mre] to your question also take a look at https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql

Comment: Is there a reason that a standard ODBC return set would be inadequate?

Comment: @bbaird I would like to get the inventory info and the items in a single query

Comment: @user2741831 Why?  The work done by the database will be less, even with two result sets.  Seems like a solution in search of a problem.

Comment: The App runs at a different site than the DB. I've been told to minimize roundtrips. It would also be good if I could create a function that performs this task all in one. But I suppose I  could try and send 2 different queries in a single request and then stich the results together in node

Comment: @user2741831 Search for "Postgres return multiple result sets" and you will find how to implement procedures that will return both results in a single call to the database.  With recent versions of Postgres you should be able to accomplish this with ODBC or JDBC connectors.

Comment: Thanks  I'll look into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was using json_agg instead of array_agg